# Updating yaml key in yaml frontmater of markdown file using find and sed

Tags: bash, sed, yaml, find, markdown

I have thousands of shared markdown notes in hundreds of repertories with yaml frontmatter. (This frontmatter at the top of the files is between two lines containing only `---`. )

The frontmatter has a variyng number of keys, of lines (*ISBN, publisher...* in book notes, *species, genus,...* in vegetable notes...). The note can contain in the body a similar key (for instance in an example of code).

E.g `myUpgrader.md` :

```
---
title: How to upgrade the frontmatter
author: FrViPofm
date: 20230620
subject: bash
tags: bash, sed, find
---
# The markup content
some stuff...
```

The notes evolve and sometimes I need to upgrade the frontmatters of all the notes. Say, in the above example, changing *subject* into *topic*.

If I know that the key is near the fifth line, I can upgrade a key with the following code in `myupgrader.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
d="/home/path/to/shared/MarkupNotes/"

find "$d" -type f -name '*.md' -exec sed -i "1,6s/^$1: /$2: /" {} \;
```

But when I don't know the length of the frontmatter and the line where the key is set, neither if the key is set, how can I indicate to **sed** to search the whole frontmatter and only it and make the substitution only there, without changing the body of the note?

I guess there is a way to write the **sed** command, but I'm not skillful enough to find it.

Comment: I have a solution in mind using sed, but it's needlessly complicated. I think you're better off using awk for this problem.

Comment: @Verpous Thanks for your attention.awk is still too complicated for me. It's the reason why I was looking for a solution with sed. Maybe one day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit sed expressions to only impact lines between two patterns. I think you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash
d="/home/path/to/shared/MarkupNotes/"

find "$d" -type f -name '*.md' -exec sed -i "/^---/,/^---/ s/^$1: /$2: /" {} \;
```

Assuming this script is stored in "update-frontmatter.sh", then running:

```
sh update-frontmatter.sh subject topic
```

Would result in:

```
---
title: How to upgrade the frontmatter
author: FrViPofm
date: 20230620
topic: bash
tags: bash, sed, find
---
# The markup content
some stuff...
```

If the key isn't set in the frontmatter, no changes are made.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and your solution. I understand that the second part of the filter (the second `/^---/`) would match only after the first part. The first line of the files being always `---`, maybe a filter like `2,/^---/` would be a little faster **if i'm sure that the frontmatter is at the top of the file**. I have only to add a test that the two parameters are set and it should run nicely.